# A Swig-like template generator for LibraryLink

Tags: librarylink

I am slowly, manually, constructing an interface to an external-API library (built in `.cpp`) using `LibraryLink`. The semi-frustrating thing is that I *have* a `swig` compatible `.i` file for the API that the authors have made available for generating `python, c#` wrappers of the dynamic library.

I looked a little at @Szabolcs [LTempate](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate) which is a very nice start at such a thing, but it would *seem* like someone out there somewhere might have written or played with a *Mathematica* back-end for `swig` at some point - yet I am unable to find anything.

So this is basically a solicitation / placeholder / common point in case someone has / does / wants to do such a thing.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Did you do something with this in the end? It's quite a large project, but it would be extremely useful.  How much experience do you have with SWIG?  If LTemplate is an almost suitable start, I'd be willing to bend it to the requirements of SWIG.